# Is there a way to sort the drop down list in JQuery using second value (new attribute)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to sort the drop down list by value2 ?

```
<select id="ddlList">
 <option value="3" value2="3">Three</option>
 <option value="1" value2="1">One</option>
 <option value="Order_0" value2="0">Zero</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1oax5yv4/

Comment: so select/read the attribute instead of the value? You be better off using a data-attribute

Comment: Where is `value2` coming from? It’s probably faster and easier to sort the data than sort the DOM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value2 is an attribute. You just need to access it instead of value in the sort

```
return $(x).attr('value2') < $(y).attr('value2') ? -1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a data attribute and sort by the dataset value

```js
var sel = $('#ddlList')
var opts = sel.find('option').sort(function (a,b){
  var aOrder = +a.dataset.order
  var bOrder = +b.dataset.order
  return aOrder === bOrder ? 0 : aOrder > bOrder ? 1 : -1
})
sel.append(opts)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlList">
 <option value="3" data-order="3">Three</option>
 <option value="1" data-order="1">One</option>
 <option value="Order_0" data-order="0">Zero</option>
</select>
```